# fedora31: cannot open display:: 0 without ethernet

Tags: xorg, display, xhost

I use as a window manager i3, lightdm and other graphic display manager disabled

Starting with Fedora-31, executing "nm down ethernet" causes the graphics programs to stop running:

> Cannot open display: No protocol specified Unable to init server:
>   Could not connect: Connection refused

xhost doesn't help either:

> Error: cannot open display: :0 No protocol specified xhost: unable to
>   open display «:0»

The problem starts with version 31 and is saved in 32_RC1.6

I suspect that the problem is related to SELinux security policy settings, how can I fix it?

Comment: try making your display 127.0.0.1:0 or localhost:0 instead of just :0?  Just a thought, I don't have a Fedora instance to test on, but it may help.  You may have to xhost +127.0.0.1 if you try it.

Comment: $ DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0 pcmanfm-qt
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 127.0.0.1:0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: well... that fixed the protocol error :-p  Try setting QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and rerunning to maybe get an idea of why that error occurred.

Comment: It turns out a very large log

https://pastebin.com/tiQ8Q4k1

Comment: No, couldn’t get away from the protocol error in gtk-applications:
`$ pcmanfm
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display: `

Comment: have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611783/after-changing-hostname-gedit-and-other-x-clients-dont-open/20612084#20612084?  Could be an issue with .Xauthority file maybe?